# Nokia S40 FT .How to add a container in a container?

Tags: nokia-s40

I have got a problem here in designing layout of S40 FT.

Consider the following work flow...

I have a form in which i can set the layout of the form as shown below

GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(5,1);
form.setLayout(layout);

Is there a way i can add another layout ie nested in the previous layout... Something like the following...

form.addContainer(layout[1,1] , new FlowLayout());

I want to add layout within a layout. It would be easy to manage my UI that way.

Comment: You are using LWUIT, right?

Comment: Yes..
Iam using Lwuit

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.

ex:
    Form form = new Form();
    Container container = new Container();
    form.addComponent(container);

Form and Container can have different layout.

Comment: I can actually add container as a component.
I thought Container cant be added Like That....

Well That saved my search..